# How to load img src from another domain for canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, image, src

When I load an image in my canvas and specify its src I use a file name that's in the same folder as the html file, and that loads the img. So it would be like this:

```
img.src = 'Untitled.png';
```

But if I try this, the img doesn't load

```
img.src = 'http://dgroover.wikispaces.com/file/view/bill-gates-car.jpg';
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Is it intentional to have `bill-gates-car.jpg` twice in the image URL?

Comment: Loads for me. I suggest that you create a reproducible test case, e.g. at http://jsfiddle.net (And what does this question have to do with canvas or HTML5?)

Comment: oh yeah it should be 'http://dgroover.wikispaces.com/file/view/bill-gates-car.jpg', but it's still not working, the image doesn't load. And I thought it might make a difference when loading an img src into a canvas. Is this because the image is on another domain?

Comment: if I try this, <img src="http://dgroover.wikispaces.com/file/view/bill-gates-car.jpg/66313096/bill-gates-car.jpg">, the image loads ok, but its weird that if loading an img for a canvas it doesn't show...

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852514/javascript-html5-drawimage-with-image-from-a-different-domain , and test your image in the jsfiddle linked there http://jsfiddle.net/ZZW5V/

Comment: @sneaky need more code. I have a sneaking suspicion it could be an `onload` issue.

Comment: @lxx, i read it and i'm still not sure how to fix it. And the image loaded in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with this code:

*markup part*

```
<canvas id="cnv" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

*script part*

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("cnv").getContext("2d").drawImage(this,0,0);
};
img.src="http://dgroover.wikispaces.com/file/view/bill-gates-car.jpg";​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqd5R/)

Comment: this line: img.src="http://dgroover.wikispaces.com/file/view/bill-gates-car.jpg";​
made it crash for me, and I am working in a sharepoint 2010 environment if that makes a difference.

Comment: i got it to work now, i was missing the onload event... i think i was doing something before the onload event happened so it was messing up

Answer (score 0):

Try out in this way :

```
> var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
>         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");      
>         ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
>         ctx.strokeStyle = "#5F7FA2";
>         ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 25, 25);
>         var img = new Image();
>         img.src = "http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/csep576/05wi/projects/project4/web/artifact/liebling/average_face.gif";
>         img.onload = function(){
>         ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 50);}
```